# Count cells based on multiple criteria stored in a range

Tags: arrays, excel, range, sumproduct

I need to count cells that meet 2 criteria.

I have a formula which works with individual criteria in cell `J5`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A4:A63=J5);--(B4:B63=J6))
```

Instead of the single criterion in `J5` I'd like to use a range of criteria `(J5:N5)` to be considered for the first validation.

I've tried this but it does not work:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(A4:A63=J5:N5);--(B4:B63=J7))}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/countifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SUMPRODUCT function must supplied with arrays of the same size in arguments. Specifying in one argument `A4:A63=J5:N5` and the second `B4:B63=J7` turns out that the first is a two-dimensional array of `5 * 59` and the second is a one-dimensional array of `1 * 59` which SUMPRODUCT cannot sum and returns a #VALUE error.  To avoid this, it is enough to give the function one argument with an array product.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A4:A63=J5:N5)*--(B4:B63=J7))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm. 
Just one more thing: if I have the range of criterias in 2 lines like: J5:N6 how that could work? I guess this is again something with the dimensions... :)

Comment: It will work if you align the dimensions, in this case divide the range into two parts - `J5: N5` and `J6: N6` and combine the results of the comparison with `+` (plus) which acts as a logical `OR`, i.e. `=SUMPRODUCT((--(A4:A63=J5:N5)+--(A4:A63=J6:N6))*--(B4:B63=J7))`